# combining onClick and type=submit on react page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, reactstrap

I have a react form in a next.js application using reactstrap. The form has a submit button set up this way...

```
<Button
   type="submit"
   className="btn btn-block"
   disabled={!pwFormValidations.pwIsSubmittable}
   onClick={(e) => doSomeStuffToSessionStorageVariables(e)}
   >
Next
</Button>
```

If I combine the `onClick` with `type=submit` will I have issues? I am concerned that I will sometimes miss the `onClick` if the form moves on too quickly. I am not doing anything to the form data that was input by the user in `doSomeStuffToSessionStorageVariables` so it's not a big deal if it does not execute.

Comment: Why not add your doSomeStuffToSessionStorageVariables function as a callback in handleSubmit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using session storage and not any network calls that you need to verify, using `onSubmit` will finish the function call before the form is submitted:

```
<Form onSubmit={doSomeStuffToSessionStorageVariables}>
  <Button ... /> // ⬅ no onClick needed here.
</Form>

const doSomeStuffToSessionStorageVariables = e => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('item', 'value');
  // everything above will execute before the form is submitted
}
```

I'm not sure if you need the `e` on the function call for **doSomeStuff**, but if you need the button then you can also get it from the event itself.